# Is the sentence "What I need to do is sweeping them off" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, gerunds, infinitives, gerund-vs-infinitive, what-clefts

I think "What I need to do is sweeping them off" should be What I need to do is (to) sweep them off"

Can "sweeping" be allowed to be used? or grammatically wrong and never be allowed?

The below is the web page that I have been read to find the answer but I couldn't find it...

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/180390/is-the-sentence-what-i-need-is-to-do-doing-the-things-i-like-grammatically-co

Comment: The complement has to agree with the "need to do" construction. "What I need to do is [I need to] *sweep*..."   **sweep** must agree with the verbal form of **do**.  If we change the form it must change accordingly: What I need to be doing is I need to be sweeping.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence “What I need to do is to sweep them off” is grammatically correct!

But, the sentence “What I need to do is sweeping them off” is grammatically incorrect.

The reason of why that sentence isn't grammatically correct is because of the verb form used in the infinitive phrase.

Generally, after you use the verb “to do”—you don't need to add an “-ing” to the word “sweep”! You just pretty much keep it the way it is without making any changes to the word.

Ergo, the corrected version of that sentence is: “What I need to do is to sweep them off”

I hope my answer have helped you!

Comment: "What I need to do is" can be followed by a noun: "What I need to do is housework" is fine, and ""What I need to do is cleaning" (also "what I need to do is clean"). "Cleaning" is a fully-fledged noun despite ending in "-ing". But "sweeping" sounds odd, probably because "sweep" would be much more usual.